# Low Pass Filter for Arduino +5V Pin

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator, filter

How can I find the resistor and capacitor values for a low-pass filter applied to the +5V output pin of an Arduino Uno? I'd like to reduce the noise as much as possible and get a clean, steady +5V supply from this pin.

I cannot figure out the frequency bands of the +5V output pin of an Arduino Uno, and had difficulty deciding on which resistor and capacitor value to use.

Comment: If it's a power output, you should use an LC filter, not an RC one.

Comment: @Hearth do you have advice on how to choose appropriate inductor/capacitor values for the filter for +5V power output?

Comment: start by determining how much current s needed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Determine how much attenuation of noise you need at some frequency f.
2. Determine how much DC drop you can live with at max load current  ΔV=IR to set your max R value for a resistor or resistor and inductor(choke).
3. Compute the attenuation from impedance ratio of RC C to achieve your noise reduction in 1.

Xc(f) = 1 / (2pi f C)  must be much lower than R.

If your C is too big, then your desired attenuation needs to be told how you measured it with photo's, so we can see why you are getting this problem.

Make sure your scope probe is 10:1 and ground lead length is almost 0.

If I didn't have the handy spring coil accessory for the probe, I would make one from wire like this. [image] or bridge the tip & ring between two test pins.

But be careful not to short anything that isn't ground.

The assumption here is you don't have to guess what the ripple frequency is with a scope. You measure it correctly.  The best  method is AC coupled to 50 Ohm dummy load on a BNC 'T' on the scope using coax.